# Remove Validation Ideal Forms jQuery

Tags: jquery, idealforms

After option Yes is selected from dropdown i would like to remove validation from fields. So I have function to do that however its not removing validation and fields are still required :(. Could you please help me to remove that validation? Also by instructions on GitHub you can remove validation with toggleFields, but it doesn't work!!!

```
$("#email_details").change("input", function(){
    var dInput = this.value;

    if(dInput == 'Yes') {
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('toggleFields', 'next_of_kin_name next_of_kin_landline');
        $('form.idealforms').idealforms('goToStep', 1);
    }
});
```

Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ymfvqyob/2/

Answer (score 1):

Edited Answer:

Your half task is already done with the change()

```
$("#email_details").change("input", function(){
```

try to use else and remove validation

```
    $("#email_details").change("input", function(){
    var dInput = $(this).val();

    if(dInput == '') {


    }else{
    //remove validation script here
     $('span.error').remove();
    }
    });
```

Comment: You are right, what i perceived from the question that the user tried to use suggested solutions but couldn't remove the validation. It could be the reason that he didn't use that solution on correct place.

e.g.
Where i have provide the else body, if he will use the code to remove validation "span or div" so it will resolve the issue. Events are really important when you are working with JS.

P.S. I have corrected the answer as well.

Comment: If you can provide the URL where it is implemented then i can help you better. It was an example in my answer, obviously that will not work as copy paste thing. I wait for the URL and then will review your implementation.

-- Added --
I can try github thing on my end but still your implementation will be having some difference, that's why its better if you can share?

Comment: Its working for email address field. When i enter the correct format so validation removed from this field. Isn't it the expected the thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81112/discussion-between-wordpress-mechanic-and-fenix-dolores).